# Find functions given their composition

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A. Find $f$ and $g$ such that

$h(x)=f \circ g$ where $h(x)=-\csc(x^2+7x)$

B. Find $f$, $g$ and $h$ such that

$h(x)=f \circ g \circ h$ where $h(x)=\sin^2(\pi t-2)$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

A: $f(x)=-\csc x$, $g(x)=x^2+7x$

B: $f(x)=x^2$,  $g(x)=\sin x$, $h(x)=\pi x-2$

I think $\pi t-2$ must be replaced with $\pi x-2$. I also think that in (B) you must replace the function name of the composition from $h(x)$ to $P(x)$ to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

A. Hint: One of the functions $f,g$ is $-csc(x)$; another function is $x^2+7x$

B. These three functions must be combined: $x^2,sin(x),\pi t-2$